# Crunching images, best practices?

Tags: c#, sql, image, razor, architecture

I have written the image crunching for the image upload of a thing in my application.

My application saves the original copy of the image to the server, and places an entry in the database with a file name and extension. (with other info too).

After this, I save 5 versions of the image (various resolutions) to the server but I do not put database entries in for these:

For example:

```
uploaddir + filename + "-1024" + extension
uploaddir + filename + "-800" + extension
uploaddir + filename + "-640" + extension
uploaddir + filename + "-320" + extension
uploaddir + filename + "-thumbnail" + extension
```

So this means i can use specific sizes of the image (for example):

```
@Settings.UploadURL@fieldImage.File.UniqueName@ImageSizes.Thumbnail@fieldImage.File.Extension;
```

Does this sound okay? Or do you think I should also create database entries against all image sizes?

**So to clarify:**

- I save one database entry that has a unique file name and the extension
- I save to the server, various different image sizes with the size added as part of the file name
- I have a class with constants in so that i can add that to only show the url of the size i want

**What issues can you foresee me having in the future by taking this approach?**

[image]

Comment: "Does this sound okay?" and "What have you done in the past? " are generally indicate overly broad/opinion based questions. I'd recommend to update post with concrete question (it may be very hard to answer this "will this approach work fine for me" as it stands now)

Comment: As you are asking the question, do you expect some future issues? Maybe it's better to ask how to best mitigate those? Or, maybe ask a similar question at Programmers or other SE site.

Comment: @haraldK - Yes... I'm just checking upon the bigger picture here. I've had confirmation from a brosky that my technique should be okay though... So fingers crossed... Feel free to provide your own opinion on this man... I don't wanna get screwed over in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth keeping entries.  If nothing else, you can decide later that you want logic to *not* create the different sized images if the original already is too low of quality.

Say you get a 320 px image... Do you really want to try and upscale that?

Comment: Good point! I wouldn't know which sizes i have in that case... so i'd need the database... Nice move man!